# Shiny: Select option automatically takes data variables

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to do select option in ui and it should automatically take variable names to the list from input data. Here I used *list(ls(input.file1)* in select option, But it's not working.

Please help me.

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "Demand Forecast", "Flowserve"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Select csv file',
              accept=c('text/csv')
              ),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t')
                 ),
    tags$hr(),
    selectInput("product", "Select Product",
                  list(ls(input.file1))

                )
))
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output){

#Assigning data to a variable "data1"  
  data1 = reactive({
  inFile<-input$file1
  if(is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)
  read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
  })

  sub=reactive({
      subset(data1(), select=paste0(input$product))
  })

 output$contents<-renderTable({
       if (is.null(input$file1)) { return() }                            
           sub()
       })
 })
```

Here is the csv sample:

```
Product1    Product2    Product3
5             10               17
8             16               26
10            20               32
16            32               50
18            36               56
20            40               62
```

Comment: The chance to get an answer is better when you supply a short sample csv.

Comment: ok...i have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see `ls()` in code, it's almost always wrong. The tricky part, however, is setting an ui item from server: you need the update---- family of functions for that.

Here is the part that fills the names of the csv into the product table. You have to add some more standard code to do the filling.

```
#server.r
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){

  observe({
    inFile<-input$file1
    print(inFile)
    if(is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    dt = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    ## Decide later what to do with the data, here we just fill
    updateSelectInput(session, "product", choices = names(dt))
  })
})

#ui.r
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel( "Demand Forecast", "Flowserve"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Select csv file',
              accept=c('text/csv')
    ),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Tab='\t', Comma=',', Semicolon=';' )
    ),
    tags$hr(),
    selectInput("product", "Select Product","")
    ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput('contents'))

  ))
```

Comment: Now, in "Select Product" option it's taking all Products in one option. But I want those separately.

Comment: Not for me; but probably I do not understand what you want.

Comment: I used the codes provided by you. In web page of this app, there will be only one choice to select in "Select Option".<br/> If I select the above sample of csv, It taking the choice like "Product1.Product2.Product3". But I want 3 separate choices( "Product1" "Product2" Product3")

Comment: Your are using the wrong data file; try to really use a tab separated file, and things will work as required. You have to create it yourself. Please test this Witout Shiny, to check that your input works ok.