# Shiny App : getting input choices from an uploaded file

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to use Shiny to get data from a file and use this data to populate a list.

The process is pretty standard. On a server.R file, I get a vector called 'list' by reading a csv file. I want to be able to select the value from this vector with a `selectInput()` function. So I put an observe loop to check if the file is uploded, and if it's correct, `list` is created.

```
observe({
  inFile<-input$DATA
  if(!is.null(inFile)){
    data = read.table(inFile$datapath, header=T,sep=";")
    list=unique(data$SLE)
  }else{
    list=NULL
  }
})
```

My `selectInput()` is like this :

```
output$SLE = renderUI({ selectInput('SLE1', label='Choose the item :', levels(list)) })
```

If I put the `selectinput()` in the observe loop, the select box works well, except that every time the observe loop is executed, the selectbox is reset. So, it's not a solution.

If I leave the select box out of the observe loop, `list` keeps the defaut value even if the data file is loaded.

I've tried to set `list` as a reactive value but it wasn't a success. How can I set `list`?

Comment: Shouldn'it be `list` instead of `sle.list` ?

Comment: I used this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504029/shiny-select-option-automatically-takes-data-variables) to find the solution. I don't really know why it's working now and why it was'nt working before, I just replace the out$SLE by updateSelectInput(session,'SLE', choices=levels(list)) in the observe loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the select input inside a conditional panel in UI.R itself and

use a function in place of "choices=" to retrieve the data frame as the list of choices.

One example is as below:

in ui.R:

```
selectInput("id", "Select Employee:", get.Employee())
```

Required funcion:

```
get.Customers <- function(input){
    # YOU CAN ENTER YOUR CODE IN HERE
    df_input <- input$nr
    return(df_input)
}
```